# converting .mbx files to .pst files

Tags: windows, email, files

Is there a way to convert an mbx file to a pst file.  I have messages in the mbx file that I want to access in outlook, but outlook will not imoport these messages for me.
Since I only have to do this once, I would rather not pay for a utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this several times.

- Install and configure Outlook on a computer. Configure it with a PST file.
- Configure Outlook Express on that computer to use the MBX files you have.
- In Outlook Express, use the File / Export / Messages option. It will indicate that it's exporting "to Exchange", but it's really just exporting to MAPI and will happily let Outlook store those messages in the PST file you've configured Outlook to use.

That should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you.  any idea why I can import mbx files into Outlook Express, but not Outlook? seems strange to me.

Comment: They're totally different products, and don't really share a code base. Outlook Express has "Outlook" in the name to capitalize on hte brand, but it's really just a re-tooling of the old "Internet Mail and News" program that Microsoft shipped with Internet Explorer 3.0.